# Getting every nth character in the string in Python

Tags: python, arrays, string

I have the following function but it doesn't give me the intended result:

```
def GetNthLetters(text,n):
    builtstring=""
    for letter in text:
        if text.index(letter)%n==0:
            builtstring=builtstring+letter
            print letter 
    return builtstring
```

Comment: Much easier: `return text[::n]`

Comment: why don't you use text[n]?

Comment: In this case it is easy enough for us to see what you are doing wrong, but you should *really* include some sample input, the expected output and what you see instead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`str.index()` finds the **first match** for your letter. If you have a letter that appears more than once, that'll give you the wrong index. For any given character, you only test if their *first* occurrence in the string is at a n'th position.

To demonstrate, take a look at the string `'hello world'` with the character indices (I used `.` to mark the space):

```
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
h e l l o . w o r l d
```

For the letter `l`, `text.index('l')` will return `2`, so it'll only be included in the output if `n` is `1` or `2`. It doesn't matter that `l` also appears at index 3 or 9, because you only ever test `2 % n == 0`. The same applies for `'o'` (positions 4 and 7), only `4 % n == 0` is tested for either.

You could use the [`enumerate()` function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate) to give you a running index:

```
def GetNthLetters(text, n):
    builtstring = ""
    for index, letter in enumerate(text):
        if index % n == 0:
            builtstring = builtstring + letter
    return builtstring
```

Now `index` is correct for every letter, repeated or not.

However, it'll be much easier to use slicing:

```
def GetNthLetters(text, n):
    return text[::n]
```

This takes every n'th letter too:

```
>>> 'foo bar baz'[::2]
'fobrbz'
>>> 'foo bar baz'[::3]
'f ra'
>>> 'foo bar baz'[::4]
'fbb'
```

Comment: Doesn't your answer gives the same result as the questioner's program?

Comment: @Harry: it doesn't. Note that the questioner has *not given us any examples*.

Comment: @Harry: `GetNthLetters('Hello World!', 4)` *should* produce `'Hor'`, but the OP's version gives `'Hoor'` instead. The second `'o'` at index 7 is included because the first `'o'` is at position `4`.

Comment: Got it. Its because of the index will always return the first found index. Thanks edited my answer.

Answer (score 2):

If somebody asked me to give every nth character in a string, I wouldn't include the first character. I would rather do something like below:

```
def GetNthLetters(text, n):
    builtstring = ""
    for i in range(0, len(text)):
        if (i + 1) % n == 0:
            # print(text[i])
            builtstring = builtstring + text[i]
    return builtstring


text = '1234567890123456789012345678901234567890'

nthLetters = GetNthLetters(text, 1)
print(nthLetters)
nthLetters = GetNthLetters(text, 2)
print(nthLetters)
nthLetters = GetNthLetters(text, 3)
print(nthLetters)
nthLetters = GetNthLetters(text, 10)
print(nthLetters)
nthLetters = GetNthLetters(text, 40)
print(nthLetters)
```

This would yield these results:

1234567890123456789012345678901234567890

24680246802468024680

3692581470369

0000

0

Answer (score 1):

### Using Python's `slicing` syntax:

Python's `slicing` syntax is much like the `range()` function. It accepts a `start`, `stop` and `step` value:

> `string[start : stop : step]`

where you can leave any of the parameters blank and they will default to `0`, the length of the string and `1` respectively.

This means you can do:

> `string[::n`]

to get a string's every `nth` characterter.

So you can write the `function` as:

```
def getNthLetters(text, n):
   return text[::n]
```

Hope this does what you want!

Comment: Sure, but where did the OP go wrong in their implementation?

Comment: @MartijnPieters To be honest, I hadn't tested his `function`, I just did and it worked fine so I'm not sure why he said: "it doesn't give me the intended result"

Comment: @MartijnPieters Ah, yes missed that, but why not just use `slicing`?

Comment: I didn't say anything about slicing being wrong. It's the best solution. I'm just pointing out that the question was about the OPs implementation, which you ignored.

Comment: @MartijnPieters OK I get you :)

Answer (score 0):

```
string = "12345678"

n = 2

splitted_string = string[::n]

print(splitted_string)

# Output : 1357
```

Hope this will help.!

Comment: Using a string without repeating characters hardly demonstrates the error the OP made.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with the code is everytime the index of same repeated letter will give same result.

For example 'Hello World!'.index('o') will be always 4 so it will not give intended result.

The best way is to `enumerate` the for loop. so you will get appropriate index.

You should also remember array starts with 0 not 1.

Comment: No, the answer posted does **not** produce the same output. You need to test with input strings with repeating characters.

Comment: Yes, so it now is just a re-wording of my answer. This was never about the starting index.

Comment: Yeah didn't want to delete the answer. Also didn't want to leave it as wrong.